# dbt selectively enable models based on profiles

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

Hello I have the following DBT project directory structure:

```
models
  model1
  model2
  model3
  model4
```

In my dbt_project.yml

```
...
models:
  profile1:
    model1:
      ..
    model2:
      ..
    model3:
      ..
    model4:
      ..

  profile2:
    model1:
      ..

...
```

How do i selectively run models based on the profile i have enabled?
Because when I enable profile2 and execute, `dbt run --profile profile2 --target dev`, it runs all models. Also the ones i have specified to only run for profile1

I want to keep the same naming since updates to model1 should apply to both profiles.

Thank you.

Comment: What you would typically use to make custom selections are tags or subdirectories. In your `dbt_project.yml` you do not specify profiles but properties for resource in a path. Your `models` dict starts with your project and can define child directories. In your example `profile1` and `profile2` describe a folder structure in your dbt project. If you'd like to use tags to allow a granular selection of models, you can add tags to these directories using the `+tags` key and you can then select your models with `dbt run --profile my_first_dwh --target dev --select tag:my_tag`.

Comment: Hi, do you know whether its possible to use dynamic profile names under models?
So like 
`
models:
    ({{ var('profile') }}):
    model1:
`

Answer (score 0):

To selectively run models based on the profile you have enabled in your `dbt\_project.yml`, you can utilize the tags feature in **dbt**. You can tag each model with a specific tag corresponding to the profile you want it to be included in. Then, when running dbt, you can specify the tags to include or exclude.

```
...
models:
  profile1:
    model1:
      tags: ['profile1']
      ...
    model2:
      tags: ['profile1']
      ...
    model3:
      tags: ['profile1']
      ...
    model4:
      tags: ['profile1']
      ...

  profile2:
    model1:
      tags: ['profile2']
      ...
...
```

With this configuration, you can now selectively run models based on the profile you have enabled. For example:

`dbt run --profile profile2 --target dev --models tag:profile2`